# Google Chrome Browser preventing connection to local running signalr host service

Tags: google-chrome, https, ssl-certificate, signalr

With the recent release of Google Chrome (119.0.6045.160) it's not allowing a connection to a locally running signalr host service.

I have a Web Application running on https and I have locally installed an SSL Certificate and running a signalr host service on https://localhost:8083/. My web application connects with the signalr host service to modify local files.

Before recent release of chrome everything was working fine. But now Google Chrome is not allowing it to connect.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks & Regards,
Nitin Joshi

Comment: *Not allowing it to connect* is essentially no information. Is it trying to connect but eventually timing out? Is it returning immediately with some kind of error information? Is there error information in the chrome console? Does the host service log any error information?